# Char pointer declaration inside and outside main()

Tags: c++, c, pointers

The program that I wrote is :

```
char* str_1;
void main()
{
    char* str_2;
    printf("STR_1 Address of pointer : %p\n", &str_1);
    printf("STR_2 Address of pointer : %p\n", &str_2);
    printf("STR_1 pointer : %p\n", str_1);
    printf("STR_2 pointer : %p\n", str_2);
}
```

And the output is the following :

```
STR_1 Address of pointer : 00404048
STR_2 Address of pointer : 0028FF1C
STR_1 pointer : 00000000
STR_2 pointer : 7EFDE000
```

How can we explain this ?

Comment: What is unclear to you?

Comment: The pointer must be actually an address to where the string will be stored right ? but here is we used a scanf the string will be written in the location pointed by the address of the pointer.

Comment: `void main()` do I see right ? Please use `int main()` ...

Comment: @JohnnyCat: The pointer will only point to somewhere you can store a string if you create a suitably sized array and point the pointer at it. If you just create a pointer, then it points at nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables defined at namespace scope are value-initialized by default, that's why `str_1` points to NULL.

`str_2` is not initialized, so the line

```
printf("STR_2 pointer : %p\n", str_2);
```

is actually undefined behavior. A garbage value is printed.

Comment: Why it's UB since he doesn't dereference `str_2` yet?

Comment: @MM. he's attempting to print its value. (the pointer itself isn't initialized). Just like `int x; printf("%d", x);`.

Comment: But Tell me , is the pointer containing a string not an address ?!!

Comment: @JohnnyCat: A pointer can only contain an address, since that's what a pointer is. It can point to an array, if you have an array and set the pointer to point to it, but it can't contain one.

Answer (score 6):

```
STR_1 Address of pointer : 00404048
```

That's an address in static memory, where the global variable was placed.

```
STR_2 Address of pointer : 0028FF1C
```

That's an address on the stack, where the automatic variable was placed.

```
STR_1 pointer : 00000000
```

Variables with static storage duration (including globals) are zero-initialised unless you specify otherwise.

```
STR_2 pointer : 7EFDE000
```

Automatic variables are not initialised unless you specify otherwise. They contain whatever garbage happened to be in memory before they were created.

<sub>(Strictly speaking, it's undefined behaviour to do just about anything with the value of an uninitialised variable, even printing it.)</sub>

Comment: You might add that in the last case, just reading the pointer (lvalue to rvalue conversion) is undefined behavior (although I don't know of a modern implementation where it will do anything but give a garbage value).

Answer (score 0):

static is the default storage class for global variables.
Thus str1 belongs to it being a global variable and is are initialized to NULL automatically.
And the '%p' prints a pointer address.
Hence, 00000000 instead of 0.
This link would be of interest to  you :http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_storage_classes.htm